# Transition is lost when using PRISM in UWP

Tags: winrt-xaml, prism, win-universal-app

I am making my first steps in Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10 store apps technology). I have an application with 2 pages and use the navigation service to navigate between them. I am used to having a transition applied when navigating between pages, but now I don't see any transition.

I tried to set the content transition manually but that does not work as well:

```
protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var shell = Shell as Frame;

    shell.ContentTransitions = new TransitionCollection();
    shell.ContentTransitions.Clear();
    shell.ContentTransitions.Add(new ContentThemeTransition { HorizontalOffset = 300 });

    this.NavigationService.Navigate(Experiences.Main, null);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Is there any other way to configure the navigation service to apply a transition?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the problem. I ended up using the `**EntranceThemeTransition**` and it seemed to work:

```
    shell.ContentTransitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition {
         FromHorizontalOffset = 400, 
         FromVerticalOffset = 0, 
         IsStaggeringEnabled = true});
```